# Creating shapes with text in the center

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a circle which contains text in its center which is aligned horizontally in its View Controller. Something similar like this:

[image]

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I would expect to create a custom UIView which contains a subview of a rounded CGRect and also a subview of a TextView although I'm not sure this is the more efficient way forward. Would this way forward be considered best practice and how would I implement it in Swift? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple `UILabel`!

```
let diameter = 50
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: diameter, height:diameter))
label.text = "Hello World"
label.textAlignment = .Center
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

// The magic to create a circle
label.layer.cornerRadius = diameter / 2.0 
label.clipsToBounds = true
```